# searching for multiple occurrences of variables in a method

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, findbugs, code-search

I have a problem with cursor leakage in my Java project.

Typical example:

```
private void doSomething() throws Exception {
    String sql1= "some sql statement";
    String sql2= "some other sql statement";        
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {

        Connection con = getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        //do something with the ResultSet rs        
        //[Need to call ps.close here. Otherwise I risk getting ORA-01000.]
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql2);              
        ps.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
    }
}
```

Since I have a rather large code base I would like to be able to find all methods 
having two or more variables named `sql`.

Alternativly finding methods with two (or more) calls for prepareStatement without 
calling `ps.close;` between the two.

I am using Eclipse and the file search has a regex option. Maybe thet is the way to go?
If so, what would it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of Eclipse (I used Juno [4.2]) will show a warning on those lines:

[image: editor screenshot]

You can enable this warning in the Eclipse preferences:

[image]

Even for larger size code bases, you can filter the problems view for this warning in order to find these places in the code.

Comment: very nice solution! However I am (company policy..) locked down to Eclipse Platform
Version: 3.7.2
Build id: M20120208-0800 and that option is not in there.

Comment: I now have Eclipse 4.2! It really helped. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid having to close resources manually (if you are using at least JDK 7) by using a try with resources

```
try(con=getConnection()){
   try(ps = con.prepareStatement()){
      try(rs=ps.executeQuery()){
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Anything that implements Autoclosable can be used in a try with resources and the resource gets automatically closed for you. No need to implement complicated resource closing operations anymore.

See the [Try-with-Resources Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Thanks. But avoiding the problem is not the issue. I know how to do thet. But finding all the possible places in the code there is might happen my problem. I have had some sucess running an sql query

Comment: select count(*), c.sid, sql.sql_text
from v$open_cursor c, v$sql sql
Where C.Sql_Id=Sql.Sql_Id  -- for 9i and earlier use: c.address=sql.address
and sql.sql_text not like '%$%'
Group By C.Sid, Sql.Sql_Text
Order By Count(*) Desc
;

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is kind of static program analysis. As there are  specialized tools for that, you may also write your own tool for this specific task. 
In that way, you could count lines containing `rs=ps.executeQuery` and `rs.close()`:

```
for(File file:sourceFiles) { 
  int openedResultSets = count("rs=ps.executeQuery");
  int closedResultSets = count("rs.close()");
  if (openedResultSets > closedResultSets) {
     log.error(file.getName());
  }
 }
```

But it should be more complex because probably not only this snippet is used in your projects. Therefore I suppose you should write some code, not only one regexp.
Although specialized tools are expensive in most cases, probably some trial version will be enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are [FindBugs rules](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html) to find this, such as

- ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE
- ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE_EXCEPTION_PATH
- OBL_UNSATISFIED_OBLIGATION
- more if you look for the keyword 'resource' in the bug description

If you are not specifically looking for resource leaks, but rather for two or more variables named `sql*`, you can [write a Checkstyle check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html) to find them, possibly as a subclass of [LocalVariableNameCheck](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/naming/LocalVariableNameCheck.html). This is not a difficult kind of check, but requires coding and deployment work.